# Angular website is loading blank page

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have an Angular 1.x website. When I try to load any of its pages, I just get a blank page. If I view the source of the blank page, I can see the correct index.html code.

However, if I click on the (for example) angular.js link within the index.html source, it just loads the index.html page. It doesn't load the correct angular.js file.

I see the following errors in the browser's console when I try to load one of the pages:

```
angular.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
bootstrap.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
bootstrap-switch.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular-bootstrap-switch.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular-cookies.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular-mocks.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
d3.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
nv.d3.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular-nvd3.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular-resource.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular-sanitize.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular-scenario.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular-translate.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular-ui-router.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular-ui-switch.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
async.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
lodash.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
ngStorage.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

And this error where it is trying to load my app:

```
app.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

Do any of you have any idea what can cause this sort of error? I can see bower correctly fetched all of these files before I started my app, so I am confused as to what is causing this issue.

It's a Node / Express / Angular app. Thanks!

*EDIT:* Thanks for the comments everyone. The weird thing is if I compare my main node app (with the routes) to a previous working version, they're the exact same. This is the main express code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);

/**
 * Setup routers
 */
var oneRoute = require('./one/index.js');
var twoRoute = require('./two/index.js');
var indexRoute = require('./index/index.js');

// set express options
app.set('env', process.env.NODE_ENV);
app.set('x-powered-by', false);
app.set('views', [
    path.join(__dirname,
    'lib/views')
]);


app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/json', limit:'50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets/client'));
app.use('/testPublic', express.static(__dirname + '/testPublic'));

app.use('/one', oneRoute);
app.use('/two', twoRoute);
app.use('/', indexRoute);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.path.indexOf('assets/admin') > -1 ||
        req.path.indexOf('assets/jquery') > -1 ||
        req.path.indexOf('assets/bootstrap') > -1 ) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.sendFile('./client/index.html', {root: __dirname});
    }
});

// Assets
app.use(require("connect-assets")({
    paths: ["assets"],
    helperContext: app.locals
}));
```

Comment: Looks like your Express setup is incorrect (a catch-all route that's also handling the resource requests). Can you post the gist of your Express app? Most notably routes and (static) middleware setup.

Comment: this is a problem with express;  it is sending some HTML file instead of the requested javascript files.

Comment: are your <script src="...."></script> tags ordered correctly? import app.js after angular.js, not before

Comment: please provide some codes

Comment: what directory are your javascript files in?  right now, you are returning `./client/index.html` for almost everything except `/assets/client`, `assets/admin/`, `assets/jquery`, or `assets/bootstrap`.